# Android stacktrace like on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

Are there any stack trace like Android StackTrace on iOS?

I found Android stack trace is easy to read. Like bellow example, the error on `TabChooser.java` class on line 15, with error type `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero`

```
11-21 20:55:47.360: W/System.err(989): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
11-21 20:55:47.379: W/System.err(989):  at test.tabs.TabChooser.onCreate(TabChooser.java:15)
11-21 20:55:47.390: W/System.err(989):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
```

How to do it when on production (Xcode) and on release (crash report on Device Logs)

Comment: Indeed there is. Do you need it simply printed out, or to manipulate it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the stack trace in the NSLog by using the following code.

```
NSLog(@"Stack trace : %@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

or else you can get Simulator logs by

Open the Terminal and type: `tail -f /var/log/system.log`

Then run the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

`#include <execinfo.h>` declares:

```
int backtrace(void**,int)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);

char** backtrace_symbols(void* const*,int)
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

which you can use to compose backtrace info quite easily.

Note that these are function calls you will have to make, and you don't have a catch-all handler by default. So you will have to consider how you would approaching support hardware and API exceptions (personally, I don't support those but fatal errors in this domain are quite uncommon).

man: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/backtrace_symbols.3.html

example usage: http://tdistler.com/2008/11/15/how-to-print-a-stack-backtrace-programatically-in-linux

Getting demangled names for C++ symbols is a separate step.